# How to Force Visual Studio to Run Website in https

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, https

A lot of my website requires `https` but when I launch my ASP.NET MVC website from Visual Studio, it loads in `http`.

When I navigate to a page that requires `https`, on a controller that has the `[RequireHttps]` attribute it doesn't know that the `https` version of the site is running on port 44300, so it just attempts to redirect to https://localhost/login (default port).

Am I missing some kind of configuration?  I have `SSL Enabled = true` in the properties for the MVC project.

I want to just be able to navigate my site as I would normally as if it were hosted on my server

Is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Right click on your project and select `Properties`.  Select `Web` tab. In `Servers` section you can change your project url to use `https` instead.

Comment: Seems like this setting affects IIS settings (start URL for IIS - IISUrl) as well and I don't want that. I want to have UseIIS = false, but deal with IISExpress independently. Is it possible to isolate IISExpress' from IIS' settings or it's a bug in VS that mixed them up?

Comment: @Alexander first left click select your project then go to View -> Properties Window and set SSL Enabled to true.  This will then create 2 applications in IIS Express the next time your start your project.  Find the IIS Express icon in your system tray, right click, and then hover over your project name to see the 2 different urls (1 in http and 1 and https).  Click on the https one to launch.  Copy the secure https url then go back to VS, right click on your project and select Properties.  Select Web tab.  In Servers section paste the secure iis Express url.

Comment: @Wes yeap, i know, but i'd like to automate it somehow. I want to be able to indicate if i want to start browser with https or http version. And would be great to set this in web.config, not project properties.

Comment: Surely this is possible? I've got the same issue. Why can't the dropdown to start debugging in the VS toolbar offer the HTTP and HTTPS sites as separate options?

Comment: I have no "Web Tab". Actually, there are no tabs at all when I view the property pages. Just a list:
References
Build
Accessibility
Start Options
MSBuild Options

And nowhere to set the server or whether it runs under https.

Comment: @PaulMarangoni, your project is probably a Web **Site** Project. Hamid's answer pertains to Web **Application** Projects. If you are not familiar with the differences between the two project types, then read [Web Application Projects versus Web Site Projects in Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/dd547590(v=vs.110)).

Comment: @Theophilus You are correct! I am familiar with the differences, but it's been a while. I inherited this legacy application and it is frustrating me to no end...

Answer (score 2):

For Visual Studio 2022 follow these steps:

1. Right-click on your project in VS2022
2. Click on the "Properties" option from the menu
3. From the left menu choose "General" under Debug or scroll to find
4. Click on "Open debug launch profile UI"
5. Change "App URL" to either http:// or https://

for quick understanding refer steps in the picture below:

[image]